# At which winter hour is sun in zenith in DST?

Tags: the-sun, earth, time

When DST is introduced does it mean that the sun is in zenith  one hour later (1pm winter local time) or one hour earlier (11am winter local time)?

Edit: The location is New York.

Comment: Isn't the zenith the point in the sky directly above the observer? Are you asking about when something will be at your zenith? For that, we would need a location on Earth too.

Comment: @Kozaky I mean the sun :) at what time will be the sun in  zenith when there is Daylight saving time.

Comment: Where? The sun will be in zenith in Madrid about 2 hours later then in Berlin, although Berlin and Madrid have the same time zone (f.e. at 12:00 in Berlin and two hours later at 14:00 in Madrid). And the sun will be almost at the same time in zenith in Barcelona and London although Barcelona and London have 1 hour time difference (f.e. at 12:30 in London and AT THE SAME TIME at 13:30 in Barcelona).

Comment: And note that strictly speaking, the sun may be in zenith only between  23°26′ of south latitude and  23°26′ of north latitude. So you'll never see sun in zenith neither in Berlin, nor in London, nor in Madrid nor in Barcelona as well as in many other cities.

Comment: @Zvezdochet Thanks for comments. Very interesting. As for "zenith" is there better term for "point of highest altitude" or is this called "highest altitude"?

Comment: As others note, the Sun is never overhead in New York. The time of day it's highest in the sky is "roughly noon" (or "roughly 1pm" when on Daylight Saving Time), but it varies because of standardized time zones and the [equation of time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, daylight saving time (DST) is not used in the winter. In New York, DST is used in spring, summer, and fall. (Since the start date was changed from April to March, technically DST does begin before winter ends.)

If the Sun is on the meridian at noon local time (and at its highest point), that would correspond to 1 pm DST.